# ¿Cómo poner un video como fondo en el header?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

¡Hola! Estoy usando boostrap y quería saber cómo puedo poner un video como fondo solo en el header.   Lo he intentado de algunas formas, pero me sale descuadrado o en el lugar que no corresponde.

Solo me funciona cuando lo pongo como fondo en toda la página.

Sección del header:

```
<body id="page-top">
    <!-- Navigation-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary text-uppercase fixed-top" id="mainNav">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler text-uppercase font-weight-bold bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                Menu
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded" href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Masthead  Aquí va el video de fondo -->
    <header class="masthead bg-primary text-white text-center"> 
        <div class="container d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
            <!-- Masthead Avatar Image-->
            <img class="masthead-avatar mb-5" src="assets/img/avataaars.svg" alt="..." />
            <!-- Masthead Heading-->
            <h1 class="masthead-heading text-uppercase mb-0">Start Bootstrap</h1>
            <!-- Icon Divider-->
            <div class="divider-custom divider-light">
                <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
                <div class="divider-custom-icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
                <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Masthead Subheading-->
            <p class="masthead-subheading font-weight-light mb-0">Graphic Artist - Web Designer - Illustrator</p>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Y el css de esa zona es:

```
    .masthead {
  padding-top: calc(6rem + 74px);
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
}
.masthead .masthead-heading {
  font-size: 2.75rem;
  line-height: 2.75rem;
}
.masthead .masthead-subheading {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.masthead .masthead-avatar {
  width: 15rem;
}
```

En **Masthead** va el vídeo de fondo y lo pongo de la siguiente manera:

```
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Para el css del video, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
.masthead video {
```

}

Pero ya sea si le pongo absolute, fixed y los tamaños, no me resulta.

Answer (score 0):

Haz esto:

```css
.masthead {
      padding-top: calc(6rem + 74px);
      padding-bottom: 6rem;
    }
    .masthead .masthead-heading {
      font-size: 2.75rem;
      line-height: 2.75rem;
    }
    .masthead .masthead-subheading {
      font-size: 1.25rem;
    }
    .masthead .masthead-avatar {
      width: 15rem;
    }
    
    .mastheadcontainer {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .masthead video {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      object-fit: fill;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1000;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body id="page-top">
        <!-- Navigation-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary text-uppercase fixed-top" id="mainNav">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler text-uppercase font-weight-bold bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
              aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              Menu
              <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded"
                    href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded" href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1"><a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Masthead  Aquí va el video de fondo -->
        <header class="masthead text-white text-center">
          <div class="mastheadcontainer container d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
            <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
              <source src="https://joy1.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/video0485/large_watermarked/_import_61b593756995c2.98061119_preview.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <!-- Masthead Avatar Image-->
            <img class="masthead-avatar mb-5" src="assets/img/avataaars.svg" alt="..." />
            <!-- Masthead Heading-->
            <h1 class="masthead-heading text-uppercase mb-0">Start Bootstrap</h1>
            <!-- Icon Divider-->
            <div class="divider-custom divider-light">
              <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
              <div class="divider-custom-icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
              <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Masthead Subheading-->
            <p class="masthead-subheading font-weight-light mb-0">Graphic Artist - Web Designer - Illustrator</p>
          </div>
        </header>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-fbbOQedDUMZZ5KreZpsbe1LCZPVmfTnH7ois6mU1QK+m14rQ1l2bGBq41eYeM/fS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- <script src="scripts2.js"></script> -->
    </html>
```

el video lo inserte dentro del div contenedor (el principal dentro del header), al que le agregue una clase nueva, a esta clase le di la propiedad `position: relative` y al video `position: absolute` para que se posicione con respecto al contenedor (y de paso no moleste a los elementos de dentro del contenedor), `top: 0` y `left: 0` para que el video se posicione en la esquina superior izquierda, `height` y `width` 100% para que ocupe todo el espacio del contenedor, `z-index` para asegurarse de que el video se muestre por debajo del contenido.

*Nota:* en el snippet el video no ocupa todo el ancho de la pantalla porque el header tiene un margen gigante a ambos lados, también puedes jugar con la propiedad `object-fit` para decidir si mantener la relación de aspecto del video o no